# Error reading excel file on ubuntu 18.04 using EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I using EPPlus with ASP.NET Core 2 to read excel template file and fill with data from database and send result file to client.All work well on development machine running windows but when publish to ubuntu server it got error when reading excel file

This is exception

```
XPathException: ':calcPr' has an invalid token.
```

This is stack trace

```
MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathScanner.NextLex()
MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathScanner..ctor(string xpathExpr)
MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseXPathExpression(string xpathExpression)
System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile(string xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Compile(string xpath)
System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(string xpath, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
OfficeOpenXml.XmlHelper.CreateNode(string path, bool insertFirst, bool addNew)
OfficeOpenXml.XmlHelper.SetXmlNodeString(XmlNode node, string path, string value, bool removeIfBlank, bool insertFirst)
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook..ctor(ExcelPackage package, XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager)
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.get_Workbook()
VINPSP.Controllers.ReportController.GetExcelWorkBook2(string id) in E:\Work\Office\Project\VINPSP\VINPSP\Controllers\ReportController.cs
```

Comment: I havent read anything about Epplus being supported on Linux.  It has alot of hard-code strings for its XPaths so it is possible it has to the fact that linux uses forwardslashes for folder paths while Windows uses backslashes.  Could post on their GitHub page.  Also, maybe this will help: https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core